# Mayavi integration with PySide6 application

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, pyqt6, mayavi

This is my main.py file

```
import sys
import os
import platform

# IMPORT / GUI AND MODULES AND WIDGETS
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
from modules import *
from widgets import *
os.environ["QT_FONT_DPI"] = "96" # FIX Problem for High DPI and Scale above 100%
import os
os.environ['ETS_TOOLKIT'] = 'qt4'
# SET AS GLOBAL WIDGETS
# ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
from traits.api import HasTraits, Instance, on_trait_change
from traitsui.api import View, Item
from mayavi.core.ui.api import MayaviScene, MlabSceneModel, \
        SceneEditor
from pyface.qt import QtGui, QtCore
widgets = None
import xarray as xr
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np
import time as t

class Visualization(HasTraits):
    scene = Instance(MlabSceneModel, ())

    @on_trait_change('scene.activated')
    def update_plot(self):
        # Read the NetCDF file using xarray
        dataset = xr.open_dataset('time_series.nc', decode_times=False)
        
        #Extract latitude, longitude, and temperature data
        latitude = dataset['LAT852_1008'].values
        longitude = dataset['LON2982_3207'].values

        temperature = dataset['WATER_TEMP'][0,0,:,:] 

        # Create a meshgrid of latitude and longitude
        lon_grid, lat_grid = np.meshgrid(longitude, latitude)

        # Plot the temperature data on a globe using Mayavi
        
        self.scene.mlab.mesh(lon_grid, lat_grid, temperature, colormap='jet')
        self.scene.mlab.colorbar(title='Temperature')

    view = View(Item('scene', editor=SceneEditor(scene_class=MayaviScene),
                     height=250, width=300, show_label=False),
                resizable=True)


class MayaviQWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.visualization = Visualization()

        # If you want to debug, beware that you need to remove the Qt
        # input hook.
        #QtCore.pyqtRemoveInputHook()
        #import pdb ; pdb.set_trace()
        #QtCore.pyqtRestoreInputHook()

        # The edit_traits call will generate the widget to embed.
        self.ui = self.visualization.edit_traits(parent=self,
                                                 kind='subpanel').control
        layout.addWidget(self.ui)
        self.ui.setParent(self)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        # SET AS GLOBAL WIDGETS
        # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        global widgets
        widgets = self.ui
        
        # USE CUSTOM TITLE BAR | USE AS "False" FOR MAC OR LINUX
        # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Settings.ENABLE_CUSTOM_TITLE_BAR = True

        # APP NAME
        # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        title = "PLOT"
        description = "Control panel"
        # APPLY TEXTS
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        widgets.titleRightInfo.setText(description)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(widgets.home)

        mayavi_widget = MayaviQWidget(widgets.home)
        layout.addWidget(mayavi_widget)
        widgets.home.setLayout(layout)
        widgets.home.show
        # TOGGLE MENU
        # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        widgets.toggleButton.clicked.connect(lambda: UIFunctions.toggleMenu(self, True))

        # SET UI DEFINITIONS
        # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        UIFunctions.uiDefinitions(self)

        # QTableWidget PARAMETERS
        # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        widgets.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)

        # BUTTONS CLICK
        # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        # LEFT MENUS
        widgets.btn_home.clicked.connect(self.buttonClick)
        widgets.btn_widgets.clicked.connect(self.buttonClick)
        widgets.btn_new.clicked.connect(self.buttonClick)
        #widgets.btn_save.clicked.connect(self.buttonClick)

        # EXTRA LEFT BOX
        def openCloseLeftBox():
            UIFunctions.toggleLeftBox(self, True)
        widgets.toggleLeftBox.clicked.connect(openCloseLeftBox)
        widgets.extraCloseColumnBtn.clicked.connect(openCloseLeftBox)

        # EXTRA RIGHT BOX
        def openCloseRightBox():
            UIFunctions.toggleRightBox(self, True)
        widgets.settingsTopBtn.clicked.connect(openCloseRightBox)

        # SHOW APP
        # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        self.show()

        # SET CUSTOM THEME
        # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        useCustomTheme = False
        themeFile = "themes\py_dracula_light.qss"

        # SET THEME AND HACKS
        if useCustomTheme:
            # LOAD AND APPLY STYLE
            UIFunctions.theme(self, themeFile, True)

            # SET HACKS
            AppFunctions.setThemeHack(self)

        # SET HOME PAGE AND SELECT MENU
        # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        widgets.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(widgets.home)
        widgets.btn_home.setStyleSheet(UIFunctions.selectMenu(widgets.btn_home.styleSheet()))

    
    # BUTTONS CLICK
    # Post here your functions for clicked buttons
    # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    def buttonClick(self):
        # GET BUTTON CLICKED
        btn = self.sender()
        btnName = btn.objectName()

        # SHOW HOME PAGE
        if btnName == "btn_home":
            widgets.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(widgets.home)
            UIFunctions.resetStyle(self, btnName)
            btn.setStyleSheet(UIFunctions.selectMenu(btn.styleSheet()))

        # SHOW WIDGETS PAGE
        if btnName == "btn_widgets":
            widgets.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(widgets.widgets)
            UIFunctions.resetStyle(self, btnName)
            btn.setStyleSheet(UIFunctions.selectMenu(btn.styleSheet()))

        # SHOW NEW PAGE
        if btnName == "btn_new":
            widgets.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(widgets.new_page) # SET PAGE
            UIFunctions.resetStyle(self, btnName) # RESET ANOTHERS BUTTONS SELECTED
            btn.setStyleSheet(UIFunctions.selectMenu(btn.styleSheet())) # SELECT MENU

        if btnName == "btn_save":
            print("Save BTN clicked!")

        # PRINT BTN NAME
        print(f'Button "{btnName}" pressed!')
    

    # RESIZE EVENTS
    # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        # Update Size Grips
        UIFunctions.resize_grips(self)

    # MOUSE CLICK EVENTS
    # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        # SET DRAG POS WINDOW
        self.dragPos = event.globalPos()

        # PRINT MOUSE EVENTS
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            print('Mouse click: LEFT CLICK')
        if event.buttons() == Qt.RightButton:
            print('Mouse click: RIGHT CLICK')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icon.ico"))
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

REST OF THE FILES ARE STORED ON THIS GITHUB REPO

https://github.com/rajivjha0599/cdf

[image: ui image]

The window appears to be transparent instead of the actual plot but the buttons are showing up on the top which happens to be the part of the plot. I am very new to mayavi and Pyqt integration and can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

I tried this with a seperate pyqt app and was able to achieve the integration successfully
[image: pyqt app mayavi]

the code for which is

```
import os
os.environ['ETS_TOOLKIT'] = 'qt4'
# By default, the PySide binding will be used. If you want the PyQt bindings
# to be used, you need to set the QT_API environment variable to 'pyqt'
#os.environ['QT_API'] = 'pyqt'

# To be able to use PySide or PyQt4 and not run in conflicts with traits,
# we need to import QtGui and QtCore from pyface.qt
from pyface.qt import QtGui, QtCore
# Alternatively, you can bypass this line, but you need to make sure that
# the following lines are executed before the import of PyQT:
#   import sip
#   sip.setapi('QString', 2)

from traits.api import HasTraits, Instance, on_trait_change
from traitsui.api import View, Item
from mayavi.core.ui.api import MayaviScene, MlabSceneModel, \
        SceneEditor

import xarray as xr
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np
import time as t
################################################################################
#The actual visualization
class Visualization(HasTraits):
    scene = Instance(MlabSceneModel, ())

    @on_trait_change('scene.activated')
    def update_plot(self):
        # Read the NetCDF file using xarray
        dataset = xr.open_dataset('time_series.nc', decode_times=False)
        
        #Extract latitude, longitude, and temperature data
        latitude = dataset['LAT852_1008'].values
        longitude = dataset['LON2982_3207'].values

        temperature = dataset['WATER_TEMP'][0,0,:,:] 

        # Create a meshgrid of latitude and longitude
        lon_grid, lat_grid = np.meshgrid(longitude, latitude)

        # Plot the temperature data on a globe using Mayavi
        
        self.scene.mlab.mesh(lon_grid, lat_grid, temperature, colormap='jet')
        self.scene.mlab.colorbar(title='Temperature')

    view = View(Item('scene', editor=SceneEditor(scene_class=MayaviScene),
                     height=250, width=300, show_label=False),
                resizable=True)

################################################################################
# The QWidget containing the visualization, this is pure PyQt4 code.
class MayaviQWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.visualization = Visualization()

        # If you want to debug, beware that you need to remove the Qt
        # input hook.
        #QtCore.pyqtRemoveInputHook()
        #import pdb ; pdb.set_trace()
        #QtCore.pyqtRestoreInputHook()

        # The edit_traits call will generate the widget to embed.
        self.ui = self.visualization.edit_traits(parent=self,
                                                 kind='subpanel').control
        layout.addWidget(self.ui)
        self.ui.setParent(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Don't create a new QApplication, it would unhook the Events
    # set by Traits on the existing QApplication. Simply use the
    # '.instance()' method to retrieve the existing one.
    app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
    container = QtGui.QWidget()
    container.setWindowTitle("Embedding Mayavi in a PyQt4 Application")
    # define a "complex" layout to test the behaviour
    layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(container)

    # put some stuff around mayavi
    label_list = []
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if (i==1) and (j==1):continue
            label = QtGui.QLabel(container)
            label.setText("Your QWidget at (%d, %d)" % (i,j))
            label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
            layout.addWidget(label, i, j)
            label_list.append(label)
    mayavi_widget = MayaviQWidget(container)

    layout.addWidget(mayavi_widget, 1, 1)
    container.show()
    window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    window.setCentralWidget(container)
    window.show()

    # Start the main event loop.
    app.exec_()
```

But I am not able to do the same on the my PySide6 app.

Comment: Post a [mre]. It seems you are asking how to use ```pyface```. Why not edit the title for it and add the ```pyface``` tag?